# How can I edit my bash script to account for whitespace entries?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, ffmpeg, whitespace

I made a script to automate `ffmpeg` conversion from `mkv > m4v` > open the m4v in `Subler.app` to import the metadata manually, at which point I'll move the file into my iTunes library.

I use iTunes because I have two Apple TVs on the network and use a 2007 iMac to function as my media server. I locally `ssh` into this machine in order to execute this script.

**This script fails if I enter a path with whitespace(s),** or enter title for the movie that includes whitespace. How do I fix this script to accommodate whitespace? I know the syntax is sloppy, I’m very new to scripting, so any other pointers to make it run better would be appreciated :)

Here it is:

```
    #! /bin/bash

#ffmp4

function convert {
    ffmpeg -i $REPLY -strict -2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy $PWD/out.m4v
}

function rename {
    echo "Please Provide the Title:"
    read -e; mv $PWD/out.mp4 $PWD/$REPLY.m4v
}

function subler {
    open -a Subler.app $REPLY.m4v
    } 

cd ~/Public/ &&
while read -e; do
    if [ ${REPLY: -4} == ".mkv" ]; 
    then convert;
        rename;
        subler;
        exit 
    else 
    echo "Error: This is not a valid response" && exit 1
    fi
done
```

—————————

**EDIT:**

Question may still be a possible duplicate, but I’ve tried to use the syntax  (both attempting `“$REPLY”` and `“$(REPLY)”`) in [the linked answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and still failing to execute. The `errors` return either `bad substitution` for the `[…bracketed...]` statement or my `echo` statement... `Error:This is not a valid response…`

Comment: The short answer is to put references to shell variables in double quotes.  Thus, replace `$REPLY` with `"$REPLY" and `$PWD` with `"$PWD"` etc.  There are many tutorials that discuss shell quoting issues.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the reply. I’ve modified the variables as the `possible duplicate` and your comment suggests…still getting error. I suspect that `if [ ${REPLY: -4} == ".mkv” ]` is the issue. Perhaps brackets requires a different syntax? I’ve tried `if [ "${REPLY: -4}" == ".mkv” ]`, `if [ $"({REPLY: -4})”….`

Comment: The correct format is `[ "${REPLY: -4}" = ".mkv” ]` and, if that gives you a `bad substitution` error message, then you are not  running the script under `bash`.  Run the script as `bash scriptname`, not `sh scriptname`.

Comment: @John1024 That’s the syntax I used in the original script before modifying anything. Adding double quotes around the `“$REPLY”` variable in the other lines still returns error w/ whitespace.

Comment: You cannot use typographic [quotes in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) - you have to use `"` and `'`.

Answer (score 1):

So, guidance + trial and error led me to solution. I quoted the `“$REPLY”` variable [as suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)…but I **also** needed to `[[…]]` instead of `[…]` for the script to execute properly. I’m not exactly sure why, but now it’s working nonetheless. Thank you SE community!

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.shellcheck.net/, it would have pointed out to you that you need to quote the left side in `[…]` calls (it's basically as if you had called `test ${REPLY: -4} = ".mkv"`, if you don't quote then it's going to be split before the `=`).